# Adaptive Paypal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paypal

I am trying to use [this](http://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive) gem for using the paypal adaptive payments and it calls for the

```
development:
environment: "sandbox"
username: "sandbox_username"
password: "sandbox_password"
signature: "sandbox_signature"
application_id: "sandbox_app_id"

test:
environment: "sandbox"
username: "sandbox_username"
password: "sandbox_password"
signature: "sandbox_signature"
application_id: "sandbox_app_id"

production:  
environment: "production"
username: "my_production_username"
password: "my_production_password"
signature: "my_production_signature"
application_id: "my_production_app_id"
```

but where do i get this information for the sandbox and application_id and signiture and the user/pass info...im sure this is obvious but i dont see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup an account at [The Paypal developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/) and register your application. I think that should give you everything you need, for development.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , You have to create an account at [Paypal developer site](https://developer.paypal.com) and for Sandbox environment , you do not need to register your application.As you create an account at developer site ,you have to go at dashboard>>account section and there is an option for create account.After creation of account you got the User name , Password and Signature.